# Is there a way to change default conventions for Update Model from Database (.edmx)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an edmx file, and the convention I like to use is different from that of my database schema.  I would like to use names like this: CompanyID, whereas the table structure stores it like company_id.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and edit the T4 templates, that generates the relevant POCO classes and add code that change the naming convention there.

Comment: Hmm, I did try that, and it generated POCO classes appropriately, but it didn't actually change anything in the .edmx file :/